# Failing to get test ETH from any services

Tags: ether, metamask, testnets, rinkeby

I'm trying to learn solidity and I'm following a tutorial from youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ      |||    But I can't get test ETH from Rinkeby and it gives me an error : insufficient funds. And I'm sure that I have pasted the right twitter link into it.                                          I 'v tried using other services like Goerli service but it gives me another error : Internal error.

Comment: I would be happy if someone could send me some test ETH into : 0x8D50b6840C0cEb89e302aC2b9d951d0e16b4b8dF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to: https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Right click on the `Send Request` button and select inspect element.

Change
`<button ... type="submit" disabled="">Send request</button>`
to
`<button... type="submit" enabled="">Send request</button>`

Then verify you are not a robot.

Send request

Answer (score 0):

The traditional authenticated faucets are having problems.

Try:
https://rinkebyfaucet.com/

I recommend you create an account, it didn't work for me till I did

Comment: Rinkeby was deprecated after the merge. Goerli and Sepolia are the current test networks.

Answer (score 0):

PSA Goerli is now the only supported Ethereum testnet because of the recent Ethereum [merge](https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/the-ethereum-merge). This means that the other testnets (Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan) are now deprecated.

If ppl need, here's a reliable Goerli testETH faucet by Alchemy - https://goerlifaucet.com/.

Comment: Goerli and Sepolia are the currently supported test networks.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need goerli eth? I found a project on twitter called faucet-dao that can pay 0.2$ to buy and sell a goerli eth on uniswap. I thought it was helpful and I recommend it to you guys. here is its tutorial

https://twitter.com/ashinel3/status/1588082420636868608